# Mongoose connect two collections

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a collection of products, and another on the reposition of stock of the product. What I'm looking for is that when I get the products, all the replenishment dates and the new stock appear, something like this:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "producto": {
    "repo": [
    {
            "_id": "5ac643ab88b5a132384f7758",
            "restock": 22,
            "date": "2018-03-04T03:00:00.000Z",
            "producto": "5ac6433588b5a132384f7757",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ac6470079b67f39985ffe3c",
            "restock": 44,
            "date": "2018-04-04T03:00:00.000Z",
            "producto": "5ac6433588b5a132384f7757",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5ac6433588b5a132384f7757",
    "nombre": "Vianda Vegetariana",
    "usuario": "5ac546f293e2b932a47b5f43",
    "createdAt": "2018-04-05T15:39:33.911Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-04-05T15:39:33.911Z",
    "__v": 0
    }
}
```

But I only get this:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "producto": {
        "repo": [],
        "_id": "5ac6433588b5a132384f7757",
        "nombre": "Vianda Vegetariana",
        "usuario": "5ac546f293e2b932a47b5f43",
        "createdAt": "2018-04-05T15:39:33.911Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-05T15:39:33.911Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

This is my actual code:

```
// repo schema

var repositorSchema = new Schema({
    restock: { type: Number, required: [true, 'El restock es necesario']},
    date: { type: Date, required: true },

    producto: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Producto'},
    usuario: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Usuario', required: true }
}, { timestamps: true } );

module.exports = mongoose.model('Repositor', repositorSchema);

//product schema

var productoSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: { type: String, required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario']},
    sku: { type: String, required: false },
    repo: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Repositor', required: true }],
    usuario: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Usuario', required: true }
}, { timestamps: true } );

module.exports = mongoose.model('Producto', productoSchema);
```

My code for populate:

```
Producto.find({})
    .populate('repo')
    .exec(
        (err, productos)=> {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    mensaje: 'Error cargando productos',
                    errors: err
                });
            }

            Producto.count({}, (err, conteo)=> {
                res.status(200).json({
                    ok: true,
                    total: conteo,
                    productos: productos
                });
            });
});
```

Why not working? How should populate the two?

Comment: I saw your message to me on another post, i’ll look over this question soon as i have time, im just a little busy for the next 24 hours, don’t know how quickly i’ll be able to get back to you

Comment: @rakan316 Thanks, very kind. I solved it but not using the `populate` function, below add the answer.

Comment: In the output you showed, the repo array is empty, the problem is not with populate, you’re not adding items to the repo array properly, edit to add the code you use to add items to the repo array

Comment: Oh nevermind, sorry, i didn’t realise you solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the following way. In the function to create the stock, I look for the related product and execute a `push`:

```
app.post('/', mdAuth.verifyToken, (req, res)=>{

    var body = req.body;

    var repo = new Repo ({
        restock: body.restock,
        date: body.date,
        producto: body.producto,
        usuario: req.usuario._id
    });

    repo.save( (err, repoGuardado)=>{
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                mensaje: 'Error al crear repo',
                errors: err
            });
        } 

        res.status(201).json({
            ok: true,
            repo: repoGuardado
        });

        /* actuializar repo en producto */
        var id = body.producto;

        Producto.findById( id, (err, producto)=> {

            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    mensaje: 'Error al buscar producto',
                    errors: err
                });
            }

            if (!producto) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    mensaje: 'No existe un producto con ese ID',
                    errors: { message: 'No existe un producto con ese ID' }
                });
            }

            producto.repo.push(repo);
            producto.save();


        }); /* end producto find */

    });
});
```